# Send the List in JSON Object to the client In Java | Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am fetching data from database using `Hibernate`, and I am getting the data in the List `result_list`
I want to send this in the from of JSON to the client.
**My Code:**

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory;
Session session = null;
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

sessionFactory = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory();
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction(); 

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UserClass.class);

List<UserClass> result_list = (List<UserClass>) criteria.list();
```

I want to send result_list in JSON Object with some other info like `number rows` and  `sessionID`

Sample Output:

```json
{ 
    "number_of_record":2,
    "sesion_id":"sessision343seudur5ivce",
    "car": result_list  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a class namely :

```
public class JsonSendData {
    public int number_of_record;
    public string sesion_id;
    public List<UserClass> car;
}
```

Take an instance and set the properties. You can serialize your object as expected.